# fwrite creates more than one file

Tags: php, file-io, fwrite, epoch

I thought using [`fwrite`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) to create a file based on epoch would be a neat way to get some unique filenames that would still be useful. Unfortunately. I end up with 2 files every time my script runs, a blank, and one with the data. How can I get php to write only one file each time for each time the form is submitted?

```
$t=time();
$dir = "tmp/";
$LogName =  $t . ".txt";
$dicz = $dir.$LogName;
$bunny = fopen( $dicz, 'w' ) or die('Cannot open file:  '.$dicz); 
if( $bunny == false )
{
   echo ( "Error in opening new file" );
   exit();
}
fwrite ($bunny,  "FN:" .$FN .",TL:" . $TL .",EMAIL:". $EM ."\n");
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the script that could account for the behaviour described. I can only think the script is being run twice per submission.  Also don't forget to fclose () the file when done.

Comment: Actually after further thought there may be a conflict if two users use the form within a second of each other.  Time() only has second resolution.  You should use proper locking to make sure the scripts don't interfere with each other.

Comment: `I end up with 2 files every time my script runs` At a guess because the html loads the same page again because of a borked css/js/image/asset url in the page source.

Comment: AS&six I think that is a good guess. Ill have a look

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before in the past and actually had it again today. What I have found to be the issue the majority of the time is when the site is missing a `favicon.ico`. I know this sounds weird but the browser will make two requests without you knowing, causing such behavior. This is especially prevalent in Chrome.

Adding a blank `favicon.ico` to the root of the site should fix it immediately.

You can generate a favicon [here](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/).

Comment: I completely agree. In the example of my issue today. I had all the checks in place to anticipate a duplicate. But that did not fix it. It wasn't until I placed that favicon.ico in the root that the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is your code:

```
$t=time();
$dir = "tmp/";
$LogName =  $t . ".txt";
$dicz = $dir.$LogName;
$bunny = fopen( $dicz, 'w' ) or die('Cannot open file:  '.$dicz); 
if( $bunny == false )
{
   echo ( "Error in opening new file" );
   exit();
}
fwrite ($bunny,  "FN:" .$FN .",TL:" . $TL .",EMAIL:". $EM ."\n");
```

Now let’s focus on these two lines:

```
$bunny = fopen( $dicz, 'w' ) or die('Cannot open file:  '.$dicz); 
if( $bunny == false )
```

When would `$bunny` ever equal `false` if your `fopen` has an `or die()` appended to it?

Perhaps you should try it like this:

```
$bunny = fopen( $dicz, 'w' ); 
if( $bunny == false )
{
   echo ( "Error in opening new file" );
   exit();
}
else {
  fwrite ($bunny,  "FN:" .$FN .",TL:" . $TL .",EMAIL:". $EM ."\n");
}
```

Or just use negative [`file_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)—(aka `!file_exists()`)—to check if the file exists at all:

```
$t=time();
$dir = "tmp/";
$LogName =  $t . ".txt";
$dicz = $dir.$LogName;
if (!file_exists($dicz)) {
  $bunny = fopen( $dicz, 'w' ); 
  if( $bunny == false )
  {
    echo ( "Error in opening new file" );
    exit();
  }
  else {
    fwrite ($bunny,  "FN:" .$FN .",TL:" . $TL .",EMAIL:". $EM ."\n");
  }
}
```

That way the script will only write to the file if the file definitely does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which was caused by javascript. The page was loading twice and fopen was receiving two different file names as arguments. See the comment of AD7six to the original message.